# Need wireless communication technology options when long range is necessary

Tags: wireless, communication, software, hardware

I need to find a way for my cell phone app to "ping" a device (that doesn't have a service plan, etc.) and make it vibrate when pinged. Range needs to be at least 1km reliably. Also the device needs to be small, around the size of three nickels stacked. Ideas?

Comment: How large an antenna is the device allowed to have? The distance requirement limits how much RF will be available at the receiver input. Without a large, high-gain antenna, the receiver will need to be more sensitive -- which affects the size requirement.

Comment: The requirement for small size constrains the battery capacity, which in turn limits how many hours the device can operate. Check the datasheets for a [CR2032 battery](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/cr2032.pdf), this is close to the device size you mention. Not much energy available.

Comment: Assuming this device is meant to operate in the USA: what communications band are you using -- GSM? ISM? Bandwidth is very expensive, especially that which covers a large distance. Neither Bluetooth nor "unlicensed FCC part 15" devices have enough range for your requirement. Most likely you'll have to share with other services, so GSM / cellphone seems a good choice -- but you want the device not to require a service plan. So that's another problem.

Comment: Look at this link http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/2KM-Long-Range-RF-link-kits-w-encoder-and-decoder-p-321.html

Comment: How would you plan to modify the receiving cellphone to make it vibrate from an external stimulus of any type? Why does it need to be a cellphone app that initiates the ping? Why can't it be some form of transmitter with a button?

Comment: This is what the "weightless" standard is for: http://www.weightless.org/about/what-is-weightless although I'm not aware of any actual shipping products yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Xbee Modules](http://www.digi.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/xbee-and-xbee-pro-zigbee-modules.jpg) for a wireless communication.
The XBee radios can all be used with the minimum number of connections – power (3.3 V), ground, data in and data out (UART), with other recommended lines being Reset and Sleep.[5] Additionally, most XBee families have some other flow control, I/O, A/D and indicator lines built in.

Comment: And what range can you achieve?